# Improvements for generic api rest service - Angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm currently working on a generic client for rest api calls, so far it works fine if a single resource is used (CRUD - /evidence) but if my endpoint is more complex like this "/evidence/visit/{id}" it won't work ...

Any improvements or changes in approach that you can recommend?

I attach an example......

Generic Service api

```
export class BaseService<T extends Base> {

  snackBar?: MatSnackBar;
  hp: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'right';
  vp: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject(String) private url: string,
    @Inject(String) private endpoint: string
  ) { }

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  }

  //#region [ Public ]
  get(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T[]>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  getById(id: number): Observable<T> {
    console.log('endpoint: ' + this.endpoint);
    return this.httpClient
      .get<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  post(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}`, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  update(item: T): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.patch<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`, JSON.stringify(item), this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }

  delete(item: T) {
    console.log(this.url + this.endpoint + item.id);
    return this.httpClient.delete<T>(`${this.url}/${this.endpoint}/${item.id}`, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
  //#endregion

  //#region [ Private ]
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
      //error client
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
      //error server
      errorMessage = `Código do error: ${error.status}, ` + `mensagem: ${error.message}`;
    }
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
  //#endregion

}
```

Service implementation

```
export class EvidenciasService extends BaseService<RequisitosVisitasModel> {

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, public GS : GeneralService) {
    let endpoint: string = 'evidencias';
    super(
      httpClient,
      GS.Const.API_URI,
      this.GS.Const.ENDPOINT);
  }

}
```

Use from a common component

```
export class RecepcionVisitasComponent implements OnInit { 
  
  constructor(private apiService: RecepcionVisitasService) {}

  getDatabyID() {
     this.apiService.getById(id).subscribe((data: any) => {     
        //result
     });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using an HTTP interceptor, this will help clean up your services and solidify all of your API calls.

A request/response interceptor intercepts your API calls prior to it being sent to the server, as well as response interceptors intercept prior to the data being returned to your component or service where you called the API.

```ts
@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() {
    }
 
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(req);
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

You can use this to set your headers, add an auth token to all of your requests, or remove headers etc. etc.
more info [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-httpclient-http-interceptor/).

You should also consider your naming scheme. Calling methods `get` or `post` is not good practice. You should consider naming more appropriately, such as `createNewPerson()`, `retrieveNewPerson()`.

You also shouldn't need to create a general API service outside of your interceptor (discussed above). Each component file in Angular should have its own service (if necessary) and each one should simply query data via that singleton service. It declutters the app and allows for good SOLID principles to take hold.

As to why your `"/evidence/visit/{id}"` doesn't work, I would say due to the unnecessary complexity of your services. I would recommend following the guidelines above and implementing a simple request/response interceptors. Then, create separate services for each component where you need data.

Hope this helps.